# Using grep to search texts with single quote?

Tags: command-line, gedit, grep

I am using gedit text editor with embedded terminal in ubuntu 12.04. I'm trying to search for some text using `grep`. I want to search for this line of code

```
'type' => 'select'
```

I tried:

`grep -r '\'type\' => \'select\''`

But `grep` didn't return any results.

So can someone kindly tell me how to search for the code above?

Answer (score 22):

Surround your search string with double quotes:

```
grep "'type' => 'select'"
```

Answer (score 12):

You cannot escape single quotes that appear within single quotes. As explained in the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes):

> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. **A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash**.

So, you have to use different approaches:

1. Use double quotes:

   ```
    grep  "'type' => 'select'" file
   ```
2. If you prefer needlessly complex solutions:

   ```
    grep  "'"type"'"\ =\>\ "'"select"'" file
   ```
3. You can always search for any single character instead of specifying the single quotes:

   ```
    grep  '.type. => .select.' file
   ```

But just use `"`, it makes things much more straightforward.

Comment: What if the string I'm searching for is in a php file and contains variables?  I'm really struggling with this one.

Comment: @AubreyRobertson I'd need an example to answer properly. If you want to find something like the string `$var`, you could do `grep '$var'  file.php` in single quotes. For more detail, please post a new question and leave me a comment here. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: I figured it out.  It wasn't the dollar signs that were bungling my grep, it was the array references (square brackets) because grep uses those for regex.  This is the line I was trying to grep: `$output = $info['function']($variables);`  I just had to escape them properly with double backslash.  This is my grep command after all said and done: ```targetstring="\$output = \$info\\['function'\\](\$variables);"
      targetlinenumber=`grep -n "$targetfile" -e "$targetstring" | cut -d :f 1` ```

Answer (score 1):

**cd** to the directory that contains your .txt file

```
cd /path
```

Then :

you can use `grep "'type' => 'select'" name.txt`

or :

```
`grep "'type' => 'select'" /path/file.txt
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: The question only concerns the single quotes, not the directory structure or any of `grep`'s other (slightly irrelevant) functionality.

Comment: @Chris, indeed, with the `-r` option (as OP writes), the file name is not necessary.